# What causes the "connecting" and "waiting" for seconds on HTTP GET requests with nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, connection

What causes for the delay in *connecting* to an Nginx server and for the *Waiting* time are under an admin's control?

I've set up GTMetrix to run daily web page load speed tests, and sometimes I get surprisingly high values for fetching static files. Here's [one report](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/idorecall.com/UToXJzRr):

[image: GTMetrix]

The GTMetrix analysis occurred 20 minutes ago. Our 1GB Linode web server is far from loaded. `Load average: 0.17 0.06 0.06` right now, CPU utilization under 1% around the 5-minute interval during the analysis, nginx connections under 1 per second.

The nginx config file is nothing special, and hasn't changed in weeks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name analytics.idorecall.com;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    root /var/www/piwik;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin idorecall.com;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, Google's Tag Manager .js also took 2 seconds to download, so maybe the problem is on GTMetrix's side? Are these random slow load times worth investigating, or should I chalk them off as a connectivity vagaries?

Comment: Connecting phase includes every low transport layer events like TCP syn+ack handshake, TLS connection establishment. Since you don't do keepalive and gzip don't expect an efficient way to serve data.

Comment: @Anatoly: I have `keepalive_timeout 65` and `gzip on` in the `http` block in `nginx.conf`.

Comment: ok, to investigate the problem (if you think of Nginx as optimisation point) share the full Nginx configuration file please